# Finding confidence level of an estimator

Tags: tensorflow, prediction, tensorflow-estimator

Can anyone please let me know if it is possible to get the confidence level value when an estimator makes a prediction ?

Comment: You need to define things like what model you are using, and probably what loss function you are using. Your question in its current form equates to, "can your program give me a prediction and confidence?" to which I would simply answer, "Yes!" You can edit your question to provide more context so that the community can expand upon the answer.

Comment: I might be missing the point but as per my understanding it doesn't matter what model we use inside the tensorflow estimator. What i am looking for is to find a way to get the confidence level of the prediction which is made by the estimator.